# Backbone Validation Plugin always validating to true

Tags: validation, backbone.js

## First Try

Trying to get the [Backbone.Validation plugin](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation) to work. I've declared the properties I want to validate...

```
class window.Models.SearchQuery extends Backbone.Model

   defaults:
       city: ''
       keywords: ''
       lat: ''
       long: ''
       location: ''
       performed_at: ''
       region: ''


   validation:
       keywords:
           required: true
           pattern: 'number'
       location:
           required: true
           pattern: 'number'
```

(I've set location to a number just for testing)
Then in Chrome dev Tools...

```
  s = new Meg.Models.SearchQuery({validate:true})
  s.set({'location': ''})
  s.isValid()
  // true
```

It always passes validation..

---

## Second Try

Mixing in Validations into Model, with everything else the same (as above).

```
class App.Routers.AppRouter extends Backbone.Router

    initialize: ->
        _.extend(Backbone.Model.prototype, Backbone.Validation.mixin)



s = new App.Models.SearchQuery({validate:true})
//returns object..
m.set({'location': 'ewf3ef3ref3rf'})
//returns object with changed attrs
m.isValid('location')
//TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you setup the mixin properly:

```
_.extend(Backbone.Model.prototype, Backbone.Validation.mixin)
```

When using Backbone.Validation, you'll need to pass `true` explicitly to force a validation of the entire model. (Yes, it's inconsistent with Backbone's built-in functionality).

As you can see from [the code](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation/blob/master/src/backbone-validation.js#L181), the `isValid` method returns the cached validation status if not explicitly told to validate all properties or, an array, or a single property.

```
s.isValid(true);
```

or, for example:

```
s.isValid("location");
```

Answer (score 1):

Third-party lib could broke it.

I had exact the same symptom today. Mixin set, validation set but model.isValid(true) returns always true. After debugging I've found that Backbone.Validation uses underscore _.without function (when it gets validation rules for your model), which calls somewhere in the deep Array.indexOf which was overridden by Stylish Select (http://github.com/sko77sun/Stylish-Select) in a way that lead without function return always empty array [].  That made Backbone.Validation consider my model as if it had no validation rules set thats why any state of my model validates to true.